# TPL Dataflow design for pipelining 4 blocks asynchronously

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Its a new question regarding [TPL Dataflow ProducerConsumer Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255655/tpl-dataflow-producerconsumer-pattern?rq=1) which is already answered by Svick.

1. I need to process 4 files of 2gb in parallel and need to read the file content buffer by buffer. (The producer pattern is used here. With Maxdegreeofparallelism = 4, I can post 4 buffers at a time)
2. Need to process the buffer and write to an intermediate table. (Consumer pattern is used here.)
3. The in memory data tables are to be transformed as per the business rules and to be written to normalized tables.
4. The in memory data is again reused for some more validations for the final version of data.

Currently, the 3rd and 4th steps are not using any blocks. Its through sequential function calls from the consumer.

1. Is this design Correct?
2. Is there any way to pipeline 4 blocks one by one and process all those in parallal other than using producer consumer approach? Could you please help me with a small sample code for this?

Comment: Do you only have 4 files to process?   Why did you select a producer consumer pattern?

Comment: At a time I may need to process 4 to 8 files. I may get incremental files on scheduled intervals each and every day. The producer consumer pattern is used mainly to queue up and process the buffer of records from the file.

Comment: Why queue up records rather than process them in the parallel step 1?

Comment: @Balm- Take one file process at a time. Reading 50 records into a buffer and handing over for processing and transformation. Processing and transforming will take longer time than reading. I am trying to introduce parallelism in each stage here. Using bufferblock to read 'n' buffer of records in parallel and send asynchronously to an actionblock for processing and transformation with 'n' degree of parallelism. Your valuable suggestions are welcome.

Comment: OK I just did not suspect that write to an intermediate table would take longer.  What is that intermediate table?  If you are using DataTables then look at that - they are slow!

Comment: The processing and transformation involves some calculations and all these are done on the dataset and its datatable. How can I improve the performance here? Naturally the calculations and other dataset operations will delay the processing as compared to the reading. Coming back to the original question. Is this design good? or is there any better design for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your design seems correct, but it's hard to say from a short description like this one.

If you want to create a pipeline in TDF, the normal way is to use some [`IPropagatorBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194827.aspx), most likely [`TransformBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194782.aspx).

`TransformBlock` works if you produce single output for each input of the block. But it seems that won't be true in your case, so you might want to use [`TransformManyBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194784.aspx), which can produce any number of outputs for each input (including 0 or 1).

Another option would be to directly `Post()` (or `await SendAsync()`) to the following block when you create an output.

Comment: The detailed requirement is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756717/using-tpl-for-file-download-scheduler-and-processing-each-of-those-files

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code for this? Otherwise any useful links also is fine.

Comment: @user1884330 I believe pretty much tutorial about TDF will have example usage of `TransformBlock`. Have you looked at some of them?